# Passing text field in HTML format from database through Ajax reports "null"

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to pass a `text field` from a php myadmin database through Ajax in a jQuery pop-up box. The text is written in HTML-format so that it automatically formats itself.
However, instead of the text, `null` is being displayed.
The text field is:

```
<div class="topic">Arjun</div>
<p>content</p><br>
<div class="clr"></div>
```

I'm not submitting (or storing) anything. The tables (through which text is being fetch) have been written manually.

**EDIT #1**

- I click on links having specific some `id`.
- That `id`-name is passed to a php script and matched in the tables.
- The details are stored as a Text Field and are fetched in the jQuery pop up through Ajax.

This is one of the text fields:

```
<div class="topic">Arjun</div>
<p>content</p><br>
<div class="clr"></div>
```

But the output in the jQuery pop-up is `null`.

Comment: I don't see a textfield in your example - did you forget to paste in some more code?

Answer (score 0):

What means you get your data from phpMyAdmin? You can get it from php file, which actually get the info from database. This usually looks like:

## according to your post changes:

PHP:

```
 $id=$_POST['id'];
    $ret = mysql_query("select * from table where id='" . $id . "'");
    echo mysql_fetch_array($ret);
    die();
```

jQuery:

```
$("#link").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "file.php",
               data: "id="+$("selector#for.id"),
               success: function(data)
               {
                   //append your data here. e.g.
                   body.html=data.key;
               }
             });
});
```

## sample from your link

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'js/db.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "id=" + this.id },
                success: function(data){ 
                    if (data[0]=='showe1'){
                        $('#' + data).avgrund({
                            openOnEvent: false,
                            height: 270,
                            width:350,
                            template: '<div class="topic">' + data[1] + '</div>'+
                            '<div class="clr"></div>'+
                            '<div class="intro">'+data[2]+'</div>'+
                            '<div class="clr"></div>'+
                            '<div>' +
                                '<a href="#" target="_new" class="b2 lfloat">Register</a>' +
                                '<a href="#" target="_new" class="b2 rfloat">More</a>' +
                            '</div>'
                        });
                    }
```

I passed those parameters and changed param to function from `id` to `data`, to make it standard. Is this what you need to see?